# Permission denied and Operation not permitted in Storage Account VM

Tags: bash, sed, mv, azure-storage-account, azure-cloud-shell

I have simple script with mv, sed, cut, awk, and redirections. It works great on my Local Ubuntu. I'm trying now to use it on a Storage Account using Azure Cloud Shell.

I know I don't have any root permission on this VM, I can't do `sudo` for example. But why can't I use simple `mv` `sed` `cut` `awk` with `>`,`2>` or `>>`?

I tried doing a simple `sed` command piped with a `>`:
`sed s/a/b file.txt > file2.txt`
And... it works. But in the script it won't, here is a list of errors I get:

```
sed: preserving permissions for ‘./sedFUMPCT’: Operation not permitted
mv: replace 'file.txt', overriding mode 0555 (r-xr-xr-x)?
./Main.sh: line 10: file.txt: Permission denied
```

I think when i run a script like this `./Main.sh` it gives me a new process, so I tried `. ./Main.sh`. Same result.

Here are the permissions on `Main.sh`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31146 Sep 21 15:53 Main.sh
```

Why isn't working?

Comment: What's the filepath to the script you have? Is it within /home/<user>/clouddrive or within /home/<user>/ ?

Comment: It's /home/<user>/clouddrive